# Are SQL data types dependent on the Relational Database Management Systems

Tags: sql, database-schema, rdbms

Do SQL data types differ based on the Relational Database Management Systems we use?

For example, if I choose MySQL will the database schema I will write for a table in MySQL will also be applicable if I choose to switch to DB2 in future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, data types do differ from system to system.

You can verify this easily by looking up the data types list for each RDBMS (they all have one, usually online).  As a simple example, SQLite doesn't have a genuine DATETIME type; it stores dates using TEXT, REAL or INTEGER.

**Further Reading**
[Oracle Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT012)
[SQL Server Data Types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)
[Postgresql Data Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype.html)
[SQLite Data Types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)